# Synonym for "one flavor"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, food

I would like to know if there is an appropriate word for **one flavor**.

For example:

- Monosyllabic: one syllable
- Monochromatic: one color

What is the equivalent word for *'one flavor'*, e.g. *'mono-gustatic'* (obviously this is just a mock-up word for sake of the question)?

*Note: I am asking this in reference to wine (if it helps in answering the question.) I encountered a glass which I thought was fairly "one flavored," and thus, the question arose.*

Comment: Have you seen this Wikipedia entry? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_tasting_descriptors

Comment: 'Simple' instead of 'complex'? You should ask people who are wine experts.

Comment: [So much of the “bad” Merlot was **mono-flavored** juice that tasted like melted jello](http://www.klwines.com/staff/3005pdf/October12Clubs.pdf)

Comment: http://www.scienceofcooking.com/about_taste.htm This is interesting.

Comment: FWIW, ["Mono-flavored"](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22mono-flavored%22&oq=%22mono-flavored%22&gs_l=hp.3...2043.8012.0.8515.21.18.3.0.0.1.352.2917.0j14j3j1.18.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..8.13.1604.y8WdtLcY5xo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.50165853,d.b2I&fp=1a944027383771ba&biw=1474&bih=859) gets nearly 1000 hits on Google, so you wouldn't be the first to use it. It does seem like something more "artsy" would read better, though. Were it my review, I'd likely opt for "too basic" or "simplistic" over "mono-flavored".

Comment: I was reading the descriptives for wine tasting on wiki and "cat pee" is listed...

Comment: The technical vocabulary used by oenologists is so precise and wide-ranging, that you are likely better served by a specialist site in wine-tasting or oenology.

Comment: This reminds me of the Howard Johnson's in *Blazing Saddles*: one flavour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Monoaromatic**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monoaromatic) *Having a single aromatic ring*

Sigh... I thought it up, found it on wikitionary. Thought:*Great, it does exist!* But the definition does not relate to taste but to an "aromatic ring".

> *Noun:* Any compound having a single aromatic ring, especially such a constituent of petroleum

So, it's looks like the right word but it's not. *Sorry*

**EDIT:** One of the definitions of the word "ring" is:  *a number of atoms so united that they may be graphically represented in cyclic form. Compare chain.* Does this mean the compounds which make a fragrance or flavour are called a "ring" and hence a wine can have several *aromatic rings*? Can a wine have a single dominant fragrance and be called *monoaromatic*? I don't know. I think only a scientist or chemist could really give us the final word.

Comment: An ["aromatic ring"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_aromatic_ring) is a specific type of carbon ring in organic chemistry, so named because of how many of the chemicals containing it smell. (But many chemical with strong smells don't have such a ring.)

Comment: Thank you @PeterShor for giving such a clear explanation: Would you say that the word, monoaromatic, could be legitimately used in the context of wine tasting? I looked online and found no evidence.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want something like "a *one-note* wine," though I struggle to find a formal definition of this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to come up with this one recently in adjective form and came up with **monogustic**.

Mono = one

Gustatory = relating to tasting or the sense of taste.

Like another poster's suggestion in noun form, mongustatory, it is not a real word.  But they both need to be!  There is no other word in the English language for them.

Answer (score 0):

**Monogustation**

1) It isn't a real word (as in a dictionary defined word)

2) It is commonly found in psychology textbooks discussing how taste and smell differ in their ability to detect flavor.

So, the word *is* used, but it doesn't have a common dictionary definition.

Mono (single)

> Gustation - noun *formal*
>
> the action or faculty of tasting.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily specific to wine/taste, but "one-dimensional" implies the concept of falling flat or lacking depth, especially used in the context of expecting something layered.

Complexity:Simplicity, incomplete, unifaceted/singular facet, homogenous

Comment: I don't think *one-dimensional* is a suitable synonym: it completely fails to reference the key point of **flavour**, and would apply equally to the OP's other examples of *monochromatic* and *monosyllabic*. Julie, you might like to read [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour], to get a better understanding of Stack Exchange's somewhat unique approach to Q&A. :-)